# Which one to use: http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512 or http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust?

Tags: namespaces, standards, security, specifications

I am implementing a webservice, which must support WS-Trust (1.3). The OASIS defines the namespace of WS-Trust as http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512  (As definied in http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512).
A lot of implementations in the web are using the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust. Why is that so? Why are there a lot of specifications (and XSDs) mirrored under http://schemas.xmlsoap.org.... ?
As far as I see it, you can not say you implemented a OASIS specification if you use a schemas.xmlsoap.org... namespace. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Identity Metasystem Interoperability](http://docs.oasis-open.org/imi/identity/v1.0/identity.html) for WS-Trust 1.3 you have to use `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512`. Just take a look [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/imi/identity/v1.0/identity.html#_Ref212806433):

```
1. `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust` is for WS-Trust 1.2
2. `http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512` is for WS-Trust 1.3
```

Comment: Thank you! My source just told me that I should look at WS-Trust 2005 and i assumed, that the Version 1.3 was wanted... so I got confused between the namespaces. They realy should put the Version number in the Namespace. Or at least change the year. Thanks again.